# Can I set a CSS-class on the node in a view list based on a text field of the node?

Tags: views, 8

As I understand, I need a module like this: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class but for Drupal 8

For example, I want to highlight one node in the views using CSS-class, how to do this?

PS

Finally I got necessary result:

```
/**
 * Preprocess function for views-view-grid.tpl.php.
 */
function themename_theme_preprocess_views_view_grid(&$vars) {
   foreach ($vars['items'] as $row) {
        foreach ($row['content'] as $item) {
             $subclass=$item['content']['#row']->_entity->field_fieldname;
             if(!empty($subclass[0])){
                $item['attributes']['class'][] = 'col-'. $subclass[0]->value;
             }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
$node = load_your_node// Load you node here and add proper condition and type for following code
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'page-node-' . $node->custom_textfield();
}
```

Comment: It looks promising, but I have no idea where I can insert this code

Comment: Hi @Crantisz You can use above code in template.php of you theme.

Comment: As I understand, this code adds class to the <body> tag, but I don't need this -- i want to  highlight one node in the list of nodes in "views" module

Comment: Finally I got necessary result 
`/**
 * Preprocess function for views-view-grid.tpl.php.
 */
function adminimal_theme_preprocess_views_view_grid(&$vars) {


   foreach ($vars['items'] as $row) {
        foreach ($row['content'] as $item) {
             $subclass=$item['content']['#row']->_entity->field_subclass;
             if(!empty($subclass[0])){
                $item['attributes']['class'][] = 'col-'. $subclass[0]->value;
             }
        }
   }
  
}`

Answer (score 0):

I had to add '#' before 'attributes'.

This is an exemple in a Listbuilder class for those which are doing this.

```
class SubscribeMeMailListBuilder extends EntityListBuilder {

  /*
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render() {
    $render = parent::render();
    $render['table']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'subscribeme_table';
    return $render;
  }
}
```